# How to update nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

There is a nested dictionary like this

```
dic = {1:{"Warehouse1":100, "Warehouse2":100, "Warehouse3":100}, 
       2:{"Warehouse1":200, "Warehouse2":200, "Warehouse3":200}, 
       3:{"Warehouse1":300, "Warehouse2":300, "Warehouse3":300},
       4:{"Warehouse1":400, "Warehouse2":400, "Warehouse3":400}}
```

In a loop, there are some situation where I need to add an integer to each value of the dictionary and update it. Let say I want the result like this:

```
dic = {1:{"Warehouse1":250, "Warehouse2":250, "Warehouse3":250}, 
       2:{"Warehouse1":230, "Warehouse2":230, "Warehouse3":230}, 
       3:{"Warehouse1":340, "Warehouse2":340, "Warehouse3":340},
       4:{"Warehouse1":500, "Warehouse2":500, "Warehouse3":500}}
```

What is the best and most efficient way to do something like that?

Comment: Any question asking for the "best" way to do something should include *a* way to d the same thing. Your approach may already be the best, and "best" depends on what constraints you may or may not have. (Where does the value to update with come from? How do you identify which elements to update?)

Comment: @chepner I haven't managed to solve the problem in any way yet. This is an Inventory Managemet problem. values to update are constant for each key (for example all the values for key "1" must add up to 100). Every 15 iterates in my loop, all elements must be updated, although in each iteration some of them may get changed, but that is not my question right now.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Why do you add 150 to the first dictionary, 30 to the second dictionary, 40 to the third, and 100 to the last? What is the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
to_add = [150, 30, 40, 100]

for i, s in zip(dic, to_add):
        
    for key in dic[i]:

        dic[i][key] += s

dic

#{1: {'Warehouse1': 250, 'Warehouse2': 250, 'Warehouse3': 250},
# 2: {'Warehouse1': 230, 'Warehouse2': 230, 'Warehouse3': 230},
# 3: {'Warehouse1': 340, 'Warehouse2': 340, 'Warehouse3': 340},
# 4: {'Warehouse1': 500, 'Warehouse2': 500, 'Warehouse3': 500}}
```